# Re-direct user to an admin.php page when admin username and password is provided

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a admin.php page open up, upon providing the login system with an admin username and password. Here is what I have so far to re-direct the user to the home page, but I'm not sure if my code is right. I have tried using a if statement, but I don't know if I incorporated it right. I have my database written in mySQL, and the admin login and password are stored in slot '1' in the database. I'm pretty new to PHP and all the mySQL stuff.

**EDIT:**

`idClients` is the Database column for specific id's.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'hostname';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Client_Information WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();

if($count==1){
    $seconds = 5 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location: login_success.php");
```

This is the if statement I have tried to incorporate:

```
if ($myusername['idClients'] == '#') {
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

and then the needed else statement for the code before the 'if' statement.

```
}else{
    echo '<div class="incorrect">- Incorrect username or password -</div>';
}

?>
```

Many Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: if you are a newbie its about time drop the mysql_* and have a clear start with pdo because mysql_* is removed in PHP7 and your code is bleeding security issue .

Comment: Its a school project and security is not the problem atm. It just needs to work.

Comment: Please try to do your homework yourself by doing little research .

Comment: How can you get $myusername['idClients'] == '#'?? What is 'idClients'? You have defined $myusername = $_POST['username'];

Comment: idClients is the database name, and # is the position of the admin username and password in the database

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: You told dClients is the database name but it is a database column :D

Comment: I would introduce a role column- 1 = admin for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code as below:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Client_Information WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
        // Debug query result by below code
        //echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        //exit;
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Username / Password Seems Wrong !")';
        echo '</script>';
        // OR
        // echo '<div class="incorrect">- Incorrect username or password -</div>';
    }else{
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
       $idClientValue = $row[0];
       if ($idClientValue == '43') {
          header("Location: admin.php");
       }
       $seconds = 5 + time();
       setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
       header("location: login_success.php");
    }
```

Comment: It says: Illegal string offset 'idClients'

Comment: Also, idClients is the name of the column in the database that has the id number.

Comment: @Ravi_Hirani is there anywhere we can talk so we can discuss this further? I have some issues I don't understand.

Comment: When you say 'do your modifications here', I don't know what to add.

Comment: Yes I wrote it but after that I have written a while loop to get  $idClientValue. Do you get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102227/discussion-between-filip-and-ravi-hirani).

Answer (score 0):

Use script instead of header.

```
if(true)
{
    echo "<script>
         window.location = 'index.php?q=success';
         </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>
         window.location = 'index.php?q=failure';
         </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hostname = 'hostname'; / Write Here Your Hostname For Localhost it is 'localhost'
$dbname = 'dbname'; / Write Here Your Database Name like 'testdb'
$username = 'username'; / Write Here Username For Localhost it is 'root'
$password = 'password'; / Write Here Password of DB for localhost it is Blank ''

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Client_Information WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();

if($count==1){
    $seconds = 5 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location: login_success.php"); // Here is the Redirection Page.
}

?>
```

Your Code is Correct But You Have Not to Fill Required Information in Your Code. Complete that information & Run Again

Comment: Your Code Show Any ERROR Message.

Comment: Nope, I want to add a re-direction if an admin logs in to an admin page

Comment: So I Run Your Code its Successfully Redirect the Page on Successfull Login.

Comment: Give More Details About Your Problem So I can properly understand that

Comment: Yes thats supposed to happen. But if someone is loggin in as an admin, I need it to open up a different page.

Comment: Ok I Think Their Are Multiple User Types Like Admin, Client

Comment: Use One More Column in DB Field To Show Different User Types.. For Example user_level,  for admin it is 1 and for client it is 2. So Whenever you get data you can check wheter it is admin or client